# Wget - Problems recursively downloading with authentication

Tags: download, wget, authentication, cookies, wiki

So I'm trying to download the entire domain of a private wiki page. I've saved the cookies in a cookies.txt file and using it with wget for authentication like so:

`wget --load-cookies=cookies.txt --recursive --no-parent --convert-links --backup-converted --adjust-extension --limit-rate=500k https://wiki-to-download`

It proceeds to download the entire wiki domain. At first glance, it seemed to have worked. I opened up the main page html file locally in my browser but almost all of the links besides the home page are the same: the login page...

I'm guessing it authenticated me once allowing the download of the home page, but then doesn't keep my credentials saved as it retrieves the rest of the pages, forcing it to download the dreaded "Login-required page" for each. How could i avoid this? In other words, how i can i make sure every file gets downloaded correctly, as if i were logged in the whole time?

Answer (score 4):

On the first page there's probably a link to logout as well, which does exactly what it suppose to. To avoid this use -R (eg. -R "*logout*") as stated [here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-wget/2009-10/msg00050.html)